# Making scatterplot with points mapped to categorical variables in PlotLy, R?

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

I have 4 data-frames storing a number (between 1 and 100) and a string, which can be either 'A', 'B', or 'C'. I want to create a scatter-plot with the x axis in the order 'A', 'B', 'C', with the numbers of each data-frame on the y-axis. The dots on the scatter-plot should be different for each of the data-frames.

To give you some idea, the data-frames are in the form

```
Name | Number

 A   |   2
 A   |   4
 B   |   5
```

I've tried the following, but for some reason, it adds the numbers instead of plotting them as is.

Note: `class.df` is the original data-frame from which `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` are based on. I don't want to use it, if possible.

```
p <- plot_ly(class.df, x = ~Name, type = 'scatter') %>%
add_trace(df1, y = ~Number, x = ~Name, mode = 'markers', name = '1') %>%
add_trace(df2, y = ~Number, x = ~Name, mode = 'markers', name = '2') %>%
add_trace(df3, y = ~Number, x = ~Name, mode = 'markers', name = '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi I´am also new but hopefully this can help you if I understand you right. I have created three separate dataframes. For these dataframes I have added a additional column with a specific number for that dataframe. In the ggplot command i distinguish the colours with the col argument. Finally I used ggplotly to do plotlys lovely stuff. I hope i have answered your question properly.
>
> Create 100 random numbers between 1 - 100 
>   `Number <- sample(100, 100)` 
>   `Number2 <- sample(100, 100)`
>   `Number3 <- sample(100, 100)` 
>   Letters A B end C
>   `Letters <- c("A", "B", "C")` 
>   Get 100 times random letter A, B or C 
>   `Letter <- sample(Letters, 100, replace = T)` 
>   `Letter2 <- sample(Letters, 100, replace = T)` 
>   `Letter3 <- sample(Letters, 100, replace = T)`
>
> Create three dataframes
>   `dat1 <- data.frame("Letter" = Letter, "Number" = Number)`
>   `dat2 <- data.frame("Letter" = Letter2, "Number" = Number2)`
>   `dat3 <- data.frame("Letter" = Letter3, "Number" = Number3)`
>
> Colour for each separate dataframe 
>   `dat1$Colour <- "1"`
>   `dat2$Colour <- "2"`
>   `dat3$Colour <- "3"`
>
> Bind all dataframes 
>   `datall <- rbind(dat1,dat2,dat3)`
>   Create a ggplot x = Letter, y = Number, col = Seperate colour for each dataframe 
>   `A <- ggplot(data=datall, aes(x = Letter, y = Number, col = Colour)) +
>     geom_point() +
>     theme_classic()` 
>   Ggplotly to do the magic 
>   `ggplotly(A)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and welcome to StackOverflow! :) I want to do this with plotly though :(